# Sorting the elements returned with simple mapping operator in Xquery

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10, xpath-3.0

I'm trying to use the simple mapping operator (!) as below

```
(1,7,2,4,5)!(.)
```

The above would return 1,7,2,4,5 as a sequence.But I need the values to be sorted in ascending order.

Is it possible to use order by with this mapping operator?If so,please share an example to do the same.

Thanks!

Comment: XPath 3 in the W3C standard has as `sort` function so you can use `sort((1,7,2,4,5))`, I am afraid I have no idea however whether Marklogic has support for that.

Comment: W3C standard example using `fn:sort` is at https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/3Nzd8bY.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I think ML is not supporting the above function.It is giving me undefined function error.Thanks!

Comment: Does Marklogic support `for $i in (1,7,2,4,5) order by $i return $i`? I don't quite understand why normal sequence processing seems to be different for you if you use the map operator, after all `(1,7,2,4,5)` already is a sequence and using `(1,7,2,4,5)!(.)` gives exactly that sequence.

Comment: unfortunately, `fn:sort()` is not yet implemented. As Martin pointed out, the simple mapping operator simply walks a sequence and will give you each item in the order they are in the sequence. If you want them sorted the easiest, without `fn:sort()` is probably to use FLWOR with `order by` clause.

Comment: @MartinHonnen the above code is a sample for using map operator.But in my scenario,it is the sequence of string values(like 84 values) returned from a cts:search and needs to be sorted alphabetically and returned as json array .So I thought instead of using for loop,I'll try using simple mapping operator.

Comment: @MadsHansen Yes, I have currently implemented using **FLOWR** expression  and `order by`clause.Just wanted to know if there is a sort option that can be used with simple mapping operator.Thanks!

Comment: @Antony, The mapping operator has nothing to do with sorting. By definition it preserves the order of the items in the sequence it is applied upon.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, [`fn:sort()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-sort) is not currently available in MarkLogic.

The easiest way to achieve what you want is probably a FLWOR, as Martin Honnen suggested.

```
for $i in (1,7,2,4,5) 
order by $i 
return $i
```

The functx libraries are installed and available in MarkLogic, so you could leverage [`functx:sort()`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_sort.html):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace functx = "http://www.functx.com" 
  at "/MarkLogic/functx/functx-1.0-nodoc-2007-01.xqy";
(1,7,2,4,5) => functx:sort()
```

Or you could create your own custom function wrapping that FLWOR with `order by`.